# iPhone: Multiple UIPickerViews

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, uipickerview

I use a multiple `UIPickerView` in iPhone application. My question is, how can I handle multiple `UIPickerView` Handle Events?

Also, I want to place the selected value In `UITextField` of different `UIPickerViews`.

Answer (score 11):

In each delegate you have reference of the `UIPickerView` which got triggered the delegate. for instance:

> -(void)numberOfComponentInPickerView:(UIPickerView*)thePickerView

You have ***thePickerView*** variable which points to the control responded to this action, all you need to do now is to distinguish between your `UIPickerViews` as the following:

```
 if (thePickerView == firstPickerView)
```

*Or Using The Tag property*

```
 if (thePickerView.tag == 1)
```

I would go with the tag solution; comparing `int` is way faster.

***How do I get the selected value:***

As for the selected value of `UIPickerView` you can do that by using the delegate:

```
 -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

You will need to use the same technique here; distinguish between your `UIPickerView` and get the selected row for that data source and you are done

```
 MyTextField.text = [theSelectedListArray objectAtIndex:row];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    NSInteger counter;
    if(pickerView==p1)
    {
        counter=[name count];
    }
    else
    {
        counter=[name2 count];
    }
    return counter;

}
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    if(pickerView==p1)
        return [name objectAtIndex:row];//name is NsMutable Array
    else
        return [name2 objectAtIndex:row];//name2 is NsMutable Array

}
```